# Passing string array to linux kernel module as parameter

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

is there any way to pass array of strings to kernel-module?
I would like to pass it like this:

```
insmod mod.ko array="string1","string2","string3"
```

There is my code but it is not compiling:

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/moduleparam.h>

static int number_of_elements = 0;
static char array[5][10];
module_param_array(array,charp,&number_of_elements,0644);



static int __init mod_init(void)
{

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<number_of_elements;i++)
    {
        pr_notice("%s\n",array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit mod_exit(void)
{
    pr_notice("End\n");
}

module_init(mod_init);
module_exit(mod_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("...");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0");
```

Comment: Not sure if there is a way, but of course you can always do `insmod mod.ko array="string1,string2,string3"` and split the string in your module code

Comment: You need an array of `char *`: `static char *array[5];`.

Comment: @Ctx That's effectively what happens in the kernel's array parameter parser anyway. It simply splits the parameter value into comma-separated chunks. (This means you cannot include a comma within one of the comma-separated strings, because there is no "escape" mechanism.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module_param_array(array,charp,&number_of_elements,0644);` expects `array` to be an array of `char *`. You simply need to replace `static char array[5][10];` with `static char *array[5];`

A normal command shell such as /bin/sh will treat `"string1","string2","string3"` as a single parameter (assuming you haven't been messing around with the shell's `IFS` variable).  The kernel's module parameter parser will see it as a single parameter: `string1,string2,string3` and use the commas to split it into three null-terminated strings. Your `char *array[5]` contents will be filled in with the pointers to these null-terminated strings and your `number_of_elements` will be set to the number of comma-separated strings.